# Update existing nested ORM objects with new values from JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have table `A` and `B`. `B` has a `a_id` foreign key to `A`.
I do this in python:

```
a = create_A(some_json)
b = create_B(some_json)
b.a = a # (I have a sqlalchemy relationship)
existing_a = session.query(A).filter_by(name=a.name).first()
if existing_a:
    a.id = existing_a.id
    session.merge(a)
```

I get a json from which I create A and B, then if A already exists in the db, I want to update it.
The problem is that 'b.a' is pointing to a, but b.a_id is None. I have the id of 'a' but I wanted to avoid doing 'b.a_id = a.id' because I have a more complex structure with lists of objects and more nested objects.
If I manually set b.a_id to the correct value, I still get an error because `session.commit()` tries to update a null value and not the value I set, I don't know why.

reproducible code:

```
@dataclass
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    a_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True,
                  server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1,
                                          maxvalue=2147483647, cycle=False, cache=1),
                  autoincrement=True)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    bs = relationship('B', back_populates='a')


@dataclass
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    b_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True,
                  server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1,
                                          maxvalue=2147483647, cycle=False, cache=1),
                  autoincrement=True)
    a_id: int = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('a.a_id'), nullable=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    a = relationship('A', back_populates='bs')

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine_sync)
session = Session()
a = A()
a.name = 'new name a'
b = B()
b.name = 'new name b'
b.a = a

existing_a = session.query(A).filter_by(name='name a').first()
a.a_id = existing_a.a_id
# a.bs[0].a_id = a.a_id - this doesn't help

session.merge(a)
session.commit()
```

In the db these rows exist:
A:
a_id: 1, name: 'name a'
B:
b_id: 1, a_id: 1, name: 'name b'

Comment: No, b.a_id is still None and I get the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that fully illustrates the issue. For example [this code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/5e4aac0e25b8c7f461cc6cb2f1489671) produces a different error but it shows *exactly* what is going on (class definitions, existing data, etc.). With the information you have current provided all we can do is guess.

Comment: @GordThompson I added the code to the questions, thanks.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the issue. Your code apparently assumes that a matching row already exists. Once I correct for that, [this code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/9579c8758313df927567bc72c5e77eca) does not throw an error.

Comment: I wanted to add that and I forgot, sorry. Edited the question again

Comment: @GordThompson The code looks the same. I get this error: [SQL: UPDATE b SET a_id=%(a_id)s WHERE b.b_id = %(b_b_id)s]
[parameters: {'a_id': None, 'b_b_id': 1}]

Comment: @GordThompson In your case you had only a row for A. I have a row in A and also a row in B that points to the row in A with its a_id field.

Comment: @GordThompson only adding "b.b_id = existing_a.bs[0].b_id" helps, but even if I choose to do that, I can't know the correct id to assign for each B object when there is more than one B object.

Comment: But I guess SQLAlchemy also can't know which B objects I have corresponds to which object in the db... Is there a way to tell SQLAlchemy to do the merge based on the 'name' column and not based on the primary key?

Comment: Not really. ORM uses an identity map where the key is the PK of the row in the table. A lot of SO questions involve blindly creating a new object and then trying to incorporate the new values into an existing object. IMO that is the wrong way to go about it. I would personally do something more like [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/4e373f44aea08a8fa026c654ef5d0f23)

Comment: So basically I need to update the existing object based on the json data I have, and not sending the objects I create from the json to the ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a json from which I create A and B, then if A already exists in the db, I want to update it.

A lot of SO questions involve blindly creating a new object and then trying to incorporate the new values into an existing object. IMO that is the wrong way to go about it. I would personally do something more like this:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, INTEGER, TEXT
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, Session

engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")
Base = declarative_base()


@dataclass
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    a_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    status: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    bs = relationship("B", back_populates="a")


@dataclass
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    b_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    a_id: int = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("a.a_id"), nullable=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    version: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    a = relationship("A", back_populates="bs")


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# set initial values
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO a (a_id, name, status) VALUES (1, 'name a', 'original')"
    )
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO b (b_id, name, a_id, version) VALUES (1, 'name b', 1, 'v1')"
    )

# JSON with new values
new_values_for_a = json.loads('{"name": "name a", "status": "updated"}')
new_values_for_b = json.loads('{"version": "v2"}')

with Session(engine) as session:
    existing_a = (
        session.query(A).filter_by(name=new_values_for_a["name"]).first()
    )

    for x in new_values_for_a.items():
        setattr(existing_a, x[0], x[1])

    # *assumes* that `bs` is not empty, and we want to update the first one
    for x in new_values_for_b.items():
        setattr(existing_a.bs[0], x[0], x[1])

    session.commit()

    print(existing_a)  # A(name='name a', status='updated')
    print(existing_a.bs)  # [B(a_id=1, name='name b', version='v2')]
```